# I included a custom view in a layout that uses automatic view binding and now the app fails to compile

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently came across a compilation error that occurs when a custom view is included in a xml layout file. The code is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".SignIn_Onboarding.ProfilePicture.ProfilePictureFragment">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000">

        <com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.Camera.AutoFitTextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

       //...
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

In the generated java file I see the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol class Camera
```

The `Camera` sub folder isn't being imported in the generated java file. I've invalidated the caches multiple times and clean the gradle builds. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: Is AutoFitTextureView a sub-class of Camera?

Comment: no, the camera folder contains the AutoFirTextureView class (java file) @TheWanderer

Comment: Packages can't be uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in the comments, `Camera` isn't a class but a package.

As far as I know, lowercase packages are not just a coding standard, but a requirement for at least some Java libraries.

Select the Camera package (folder), hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and refactor it to `camera`.